# upload file and save it with original name

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to have web form for upload files. I want save uploaded file with original name.

I have this PHP code:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input type="file" name="file" /> <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

<?php
  if ( ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ) {
    $fieldname = $_REQUEST['file'];
    $tmpfile = $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'];

    $info = pathinfo($tmpfile);
    $filename = 'newfile.' . $info['extension'];

    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $filename;

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpfile, $uploadfile)) {
      echo $uploadfile;
    }

  }
?>
```

but after user upload file I have `tmp_name` file on server.

What I need: user upload file `photo123.jpg` - I want `photo123.jpg` on server. User upload `firefox.exe` - I want `firefox.exe`

Comment: check this `http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `$_FILES['file']['name']`

```
if ( ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ) {
    $tmpfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $filename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpfile, $uploadfile)) {
      echo $uploadfile;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$fieldname = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

instead of  `$fieldname = $_REQUEST['file'];`

Comment: please let me know if it's working for you.

Comment: I don't see how this helps at all; judging from the code shared, `$fieldname` should rightfully be `"file"` and not the uploaded file name.